# How many resource records for multiple MX values?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I'm trying to write a general interface that can be used for setting resource records in a DNS service such as AWS Route 53. Things seemed to be working until I noticed that Route 53 replaced my first MX value with a priority of 10 with the second MX value with a priority of 20.

Then I read in an [AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=88634) that AWS will only support *one* actual MX records, and one has to combine the multiple values into a single value, separated by newlined. This confuses me a bit because I thought sure other DNS services allowed different TTL values for individual MX entries—so how can they do this if MX values are actually stored as one record?

Do all DNS servers store MX records as a single resource record, or is this business of combining into one resource record specific to Route 53? I couldn't find anything about it in other documents. Is this there an RFC that covers this?

*Update:* This turned out to be my mistake. I had forgotten that Route 53 groups multiple values for a single name and type into a *resource record set*. This business of combining values into multiple lines is only for the web UI, apparently. Through the API one must group together all the values for the same name and type into the same "resource record set", and use an `UPSERT` to set them all at the same time. So Route 53 is still apparently storing values separately, it's just that the Java SDK 2 API requires the values to be grouped into a "set" associated with a "key" of the resource record type and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is completely answered in the [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) standards track document, section 3.3.9, and [RFC 974](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc974).

It is short, I'll copy it here:

> 3.3.9. MX RDATA format
>
> ```
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                  PREFERENCE                   |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> /                   EXCHANGE                    /
> /                                               /
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> ```
>
> where:
>
> PREFERENCE      A 16 bit integer which specifies the preference given
> to
> this RR among others at the same owner.  Lower values
> are preferred.
>
> EXCHANGE        A  which specifies a host willing to act
> as
> a mail exchange for the owner name.
>
> MX records cause type A additional section processing for the host
> specified by EXCHANGE.  The use of MX RRs is explained in detail in
> [RFC-974].

So, a single MX record could only contain a single mail exchanged fully-qualified domain name, which must resolve to one or more A or AAAA records. There is no way to specify more that one mail exchanger name in a single MX record.

DNS specification only governs how this information is presented to a caller on query. Nobody says how DNS server should store this data in their software. Anything will do, as long as server behaves like in the standard. So it is unknown how all those records are stored, but that's doesn't matter at all.

If you have a single MX record which referenced name resolves to a more than one address record, you'll get a simple load balancing between those addresses. This is because DNS resolver on a sending host will select an address at random and return in to the caller process, in this phase working as SMTP client which searches for and connects to a remote mail exchanger.

You can have more than one MX record, with same or different preference values. If preference values are the same, how to select a particular host to connect to is left to a discretion of a sending server. For example, Postfix will by default load-balance connections, while others might behave differently.

Comment: "So, a single MX record could only contain a single mail exchanged fully-qualified domain name, which must resolve to one or more A or AAAA records. There is no way to specify more that one mail exchanger name in a single MX record." OK, this is wonderful information. Now can you tie this back to the original question and explain how AWS Route 53 uses MX values? Are they just blatantly non-standards compliant? Is this common for DNS providers to combine MX records, or is AWS alone in this? Thanks.

Comment: Since it is impossible to combine several records into one in a standard and compatible way, nobody is doing that, including AWS. When building DNS replies, nobody will go against standards, because everybody else won't be able to understand them. Either what you talking about is a kind of city legend, or it may be that AWS just presents it to you as a single field, probably also stores it internally that way, but when it comes to a DNS protocol it works as described in the standards, i.e. returns manyl MX records or a MX record that is pointing to a many A records with the same name.

Comment: "… a city legend …" haha I didn't write this question because of that link. I found the link because Route 53 is ignoring all my `MX` records and `TXT` records except the last one I set (via the SDK). In a day or two I'll try to combine them as the link above describes. I'm creating a generalized API for DNS providers, so that's why I'm interested if this is common practice or specific to Route 53.

Comment: Again, all we can say from this link is that it looks like Amazon stores all MX info in a single database record, and they also present it like this to users. It doesn't mean anything about how it gets interpreted when this info queiried with DNS. DNS protocol doesn't allow multiple data in a single MX record, so even if Amazon stores all of them in a single DB record, they are required to split them and present via DNS as individual MX records in their DNS replies. There is no way it would work at all otherwise.

Comment: Turns out the multi-line `MX` setting for Route 53 didn't work either; I get a `software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53.model.InvalidChangeBatchException: [Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: MXRRDATANotTwoFields (MX record doesn't have 2 fields)`. I've raised the question at [aws-sdk-java-v2 Issue #1484](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1484); hopefully I'll get an answer. For now I'm stuck and don't even know what Route 53 expects.

Comment: I found my problem. Route 53 apparently does allow multiple values as separate entries, but using the Java SDK 2 API one has to group the values for the same name and type into a "resource record set". So there is no RFC 1035 violation, just a peculiarity of the Route 53 API model. I updated the answer, and explained it more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58572927/421049. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Except few cases, like the `CNAME` type, resource records can appear multiple times for the same owner, which is why it is called "resource records sets" (there is not inherent order).

So you can totally have multiple MX records, with the same or different weights. This is what comes from generic DNS specifications but then DNS providers are free to do their own constraints. However each record stands by itself, you can not put 2 `MX` records into one, this makes no sense.

As for

> other DNS services allowed different TTL values for individual MX entries

(this works for any kind of records, not just MX), this was mostly true at the beginning of the DNS, but is not true anymore nowadays, specifically because of DNSSEC.

All records in a given resource records set must have the same TTL.

[RFC 8499 (aka BCP 19) "DNS Terminology"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8499) explains it:

> RRset:  A set of resource records "with the same label, class and
> type, but with different data" (according to [RFC2181],
> Section 5).  Also written as "RRSet" in some documents.  As a
> clarification, "same label" in this definition means "same owner
> name".  In addition, [RFC2181] states that "the TTLs of all RRs in
> an RRSet must be the same".

[RFC 2181 is "Clarifications to the DNS Specification"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181):

> 5.2. TTLs of RRs in an RRSet
>
> Resource Records also have a time to live (TTL).  It is possible
> for    the RRs in an RRSet to have different TTLs.  No uses for this
> have    been found that cannot be better accomplished in other ways.
> This    can, however, cause partial replies (not marked "truncated")
> from a    caching server, where the TTLs for some but not all the RRs
> in the    RRSet have expired.
>
> Consequently the use of differing TTLs in an RRSet is hereby
> deprecated, the TTLs of all RRs in an RRSet must be the same.

The RRSIG record in DNSSEC (§3.1 of RFC 4034) covers a whole RRset, and has the original TTL in it, so all records of the RRset must share the same TTL.

Comment: Wonderful information; thanks. It's hard to choose which response to choose as the "answer", but I went with the other one because it contained direct information from an RFC about the format of a single `MX` record, which I hadn't seen before. But your response was really useful, too. Thank you.